# Hammer js - close menu swipe right - vertical swipe interfering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hammer.js

I want to swipe right to close my menu. I want users to be able to scroll up and down through my menu given that the menu may be long on mobile.

However if you swipe up or down and you swipe to the right a little bit, it closes the menu.

http://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/gpBLPp/

```
$('.menu_toggle').click(function (event) {
    $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
});

new Hammer(document.getElementById('menu')).on("panright", function(ev) {
    $('.menu').removeClass('active');
});
```

Is there a simple way round this?
I almost want a threshold to make it obvious.

Like a simple calculation - IF distance traveled to the right is greater than distance traveled vertically = swipe right.
Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use swipe events. Hammer JS provides you clear separation between swipe up/down/right/left. You can put a higher threshold for swipe right event if you want to avoid it on vertical scroll.